# building gcc-13.2.0 cross compiler, generated makefile causes errors

Tags: raspberry-pi, gcc, cross-compilation

I am trying to build a cross compiler for my Raspberry Pi Zero that runs on a Raspberry Pi 4. I used

`../configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-multilib --disable-fixincludes --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-float=hard --with-fpu=vfp --with-cpu=arm1176jzf-s`

and the makefile generated keeps having fatal errors.

The error is on a line reading
`` +@r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \ ``. I don't know how to debug makefile, I would just think the auto generated makefile would work.

The full section is

```
all:
        @: $(MAKE); $(unstage)
        +@r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
        s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
          $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) \
                $(PGO_BUILD_GEN_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-host all-target \
        && :
```

Comment: The `\ ` at the end of the line means it continues on the next line. The `+` and `@` characters at the start of the line mean things to make, for debugging purposes you can ignore them. So you are left with a shell line that sets `r` to the current directory, `s`s to the src_dir, and runs a new copy of `make` to build `all-host` and `all-target`. Does this make sense to you or do I need to break it down further?  Since you don't tell us what the fatal error is, it is hard to help you further.